# Changing DateTime from AM to PM

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `DateTime` variable. I'm trying to toggle between AM and PM. Can't seem to figure out the correct way of doing that...

```
DateTime someTime = DateTime.now();
```

Say `someTime` is equal to 14:00. When I set it to am, it should become 2:00. Then when setting it to pm it should become 14:00.

Comment: You will need to construct a new `DateTime` object based on the old `DateTime` components, offsetting the hour by 12 hours as appropriate.  That said, it's not clear why you want to do that, and this smells of a wrong approach to solve some other problem.  You say "set it to am"; set *what*?  You say "when setting it to pm it should be 14:00", but 14:00 is a 24-hour time and would be inappropriate when used with PM.

Answer (score -1):

See DateFormat docs:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

You can use DateFormat by using the `intl` package:
https://pub.dev/packages/intl

See this example when intl is imported:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(now);
print(formattedDate);
```

This prints a result of `4:41 PM`, it would be AM of course if it was the morning.

Comment: The OP wants to change the `DateTime` itself, not change how it's displayed.